# Overlord: Raising Hell does not start from Steam

Tags: pc, steam, overlord

When clicking "play" on *Overlord: Raising Hell* in the Steam library the game won't run.

- When you choose "Play Overlord Raising Hell", the game does not start
  and exits without an error.
- When you choose "Configure Overlord: Raising Hell", the game gives an error: "executable not found".

The main game does launch, but the expansion is not enabled.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried verifying cache integrity?

Comment: And if that doesn't work, perhaps closing Steam and reopening would work.

Comment: I found out what the problem was, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that both Overlord and Overlord: Raising Hell should be installed in the Steam Library on the same hard disk. When they are both installed on separate disks the game will not work and you'll get this error.

So I have reinstalled it on the same hard disk and now it works.

Comment: Makes sense, if it's an expansion.

Comment: Ah, that does make sense. That would have been a useful bit of information to include in the question :)